# How do I assign an element from one list as the value of an element from another list and print the result?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I need to assign an element from one list as the value of an element in another list. How do I do it?

I had a string whose characters I stored as a list-A and I have another list-B whose elements will act like variables. I tried using a for loop where each iteration in the list-B will contain elements from list-A as their value. I know it is picking the value from the last iteration of the List-A. I tried using a nested for loop; the First one for the List-B and the second one for the List-A. All it does is print all the elements of list-A for every iteration of List-B.

```
item = "Cheese Burger"
ends = []
end_num = []
for i in range(1,13):
    end_num.append(i)
print(f"end_num = {end_num} \n")

for num in end_num:
    end = f"end{num}"
    #print(end)
    ends.append(end)
print(f"end list = {ends} \n")

characters = []
for char in item:
    characters.append(char)
characters.pop(6)
print("Character list = ", characters, "\n")
#print(len(characters))

for iteration in ends:
    result = '{0} = "{1}"'.format(iteration,char)           
    print(result)
```

For a string "Cheese Burger" as input, the expected output is:

```
end1 = "C"
end2 = "h"
end3 = "e"
end4 = "e"
end5 = "s"
end6 = "e"
end7 = "B"
end8 = "u"
end9 = "r"
end10 = "g"
end11 = "e"
end12 = "r"
```

Actual output :

```
end1 = "r"
end2 = "r"
end3 = "r"
end4 = "r"
end5 = "r"
end6 = "r"
end7 = "r"
end8 = "r"
end9 = "r"
end10 = "r"
end11 = "r"
end12 = "r"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last `for` loop with:

```
for i in range(len(ends)):
    result = '{0} = "{1}"'.format(ends[i],characters[i])
    print(result)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55449114

Also, in the first `for` loop, consider using `for i in range(1,len(item))` instead of hard-coding the number of characters with `range(1,13)`

Edit: to make a general purpose solution, instead of using `characters.pop(6)` which only works if there's a single space to remove at the 6th position, you can remove all spaces from the input string with `item.replace(" ","")`:

```
item = "Che ese Bur  ger"
item = item.replace(" ","")
print(item)
```

which will output `CheeseBurger`.

You'll then need to update the range of the first `for` loop:

```
for i in range(1,len(item)+1):
```

so that the sizes of `end_num` and `item` match.

2nd demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55449114-2 you can change the input string to anything you want.

However, note that there's a much simpler and shorter solution for outputting the same thing as your code:

```
item = "Che ese Bur  ger"
item = item.replace(" ","")
for i in range(1,len(item)+1):
  result = 'ends{0} = "{1}"'.format(i,item[i-1])
  print(result)
```

3rd demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55449228-3

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works well for the string where there is exactly one space, now how do we make a general purpose solution where there the multiple white spaces are there as well as where there is not space. I think this has to do with if else condition.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ShivamThaman please consider marking my answer as accepted (check mark on the left) if it worked for you.